# Remove category url form listing page

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to remove parent category in listing page

i tried this Programmatically But it won't work:

Open the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Url` and comment the below line

```
//if (null === $parentPath) {
//    $parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
//}
//elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
    $parentPath = '';
//}
```

this is my url `http://domain.com/baby-care/baby-body-care-products-online/baby-cream-perfumes-oils-lotions-for-skin.html`

but i want `http://totaltoys.com/baby-cream-perfumes-oils-lotions-for-skin.html`

How I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**To remove category paths from product url** set `"Use Categories Path for Product URLs"` to `"No"` under `System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimizations`.

**To remove parent category path from child category url** 
Rewrite class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Url`
override method `public function getCategoryRequestPath($category, $parentPath)` like below

```
public function getCategoryRequestPath($category, $parentPath)
    {
        $storeId = $category->getStoreId();
        $idPath  = $this->generatePath('id', null, $category);
        $suffix  = $this->getCategoryUrlSuffix($storeId);

        if (isset($this->_rewrites[$idPath])) {
            $this->_rewrite = $this->_rewrites[$idPath];
            $existingRequestPath = $this->_rewrites[$idPath]->getRequestPath();
        }

        if ($category->getUrlKey() == '') {
            $urlKey = $this->getCategoryModel()->formatUrlKey($category->getName());
        }
        else {
            $urlKey = $this->getCategoryModel()->formatUrlKey($category->getUrlKey());
        }

        $categoryUrlSuffix = $this->getCategoryUrlSuffix($category->getStoreId());
        // Code commented to remove parent category path from child category path
        //if (null === $parentPath) {
            //$parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
        //}
        //elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
            $parentPath = '';
        //}
        $parentPath = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrlPath($parentPath,
                                                                           true, $category->getStoreId());

        $requestPath = $parentPath . $urlKey . $categoryUrlSuffix;
        if (isset($existingRequestPath) && $existingRequestPath == $requestPath . $suffix) {
            return $existingRequestPath;
        }

        if ($this->_deleteOldTargetPath($requestPath, $idPath, $storeId)) {
            return $requestPath;
        }

        return $this->getUnusedPath($category->getStoreId(), $requestPath,
                                    $this->generatePath('id', null, $category)
        );
    }
```

Modified below code

```
if (null === $parentPath) {
            $parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
        }
        elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
            $parentPath = '';
        }
```

to

```
//if (null === $parentPath) {
            //$parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
        //}
        //elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
            $parentPath = '';
        //}
```

Comment: i already done but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Go to `System > Configuration > Catalog > Search Engine Optimizations` find  `Use Categories Path for Product URLs` and make this as `No` and save it and make index managment and check the urls

Comment: i already done but it's not working

Comment: u did index management also ?

Comment: No luck i already did it